# Training SVM Classifier after HOG Features extraction

Tags: opencv, svm

I am trying to train a SVM Classifier and use the same for Human Detection. I have around 3000 positive and 3000 negative samples to be used for training. HOG Features are used for feature Extraction (I am not making use of any OpenCV Code for HOG, rather histograms are calculated using separate piece of C++ Code). But for training and prediction I am relied on OpenCV SVM.train() and SVM.predict() classes.
When I run the Code, I get the SVM Classifier dumped (using "SVM.save"), but when i use the same for predicting the Images (Here i am using the same Images which were used for training) i see almost all the Negative Images are falsely-classified as positive. 
I even tried varying the "CvSVMParams params", but it did not yield me any result.

The params used were :

```
params.svm_type    = CvSVM::C_SVC;
params.kernel_type = CvSVM::RBF;
params.term_crit   = cvTermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_ITER+CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 1000, FLT_EPSILON);
```

Any suggestions/advice on this would be of great help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How did you setup the data for training ? That can make a difference in the success of your trained data

Comment: My guess is you should change label for negative samples to '-1' instead '0'. Did you check all pre-settings or predefaults for OpenCV?